# How to get data column from second table that have common to the third table which third table have common on the first table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here's my first table which is `tb_finalpay_detail`. 
`tb_finalpay_detail` inserts the data `(fpayID)` to the second table which is `tb_finalpay`.
I can't insert the data of `cooploanID`.

```
fpaydetID  fpayID  cooploanID
    1         1         0
```

Here's my second table which is `tb_finalpay`
`tb_finalpay` gets the data `(coopmemID)` to the third table which is `tb_cooploan_master`

```
fpayID        coopmemID
  1     coop2554853ec74ca6b7c2
```

Here's my third table which is `tb_cooploan_master`
I'm trying to pass the data `(cooploanID)` to `tb_finalpay_detail`

```
clmstIDy        coopmemID          cooploanID
    1    coop2554853ec74ca6b7c2        19
```

How can I insert the field `(cooploanID)` from `tb_cooploan_master` that has common to tb_finalpay which is `(fpayID)` and Insert it to `tb_finalpay_detail`?

I've tried this but it won't work.

```
"INSERT INTO tb_finalpay_detail (cooploanID)
 SELECT cooploanID FROM tb_cooploan_master INNER JOIN tb_finalpay ON tb_cooploan_master.coopmemID = tb_finalpay.coopmemID
 WHERE coopmemID='coopmemID'";
```

And also this

```
"INSERT INTO tb_finalpay_detail (cooploanID) INNER JOIN tb_finalpay ON tb_finalpay_detail.fpayID = tb_finalpay.fpayID
(SELECT cooploanID FROM tb_cooploan_master INNER JOIN tb_finalpay ON tb_cooploan_master.coopmemID = tb_finalpay.coopmemID
WHERE coopmemID='$coopmemID')";
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: what fields are autonumeric?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza All of the first fields are autonumeric

Comment: so where you get `coopmemID` for the second table?

Comment: I think is easy if you say what data you have to start with. Because now im not sure where you get `cooploanID`

Comment: I see no answer yet. This will help prepare better question to get more attention. Please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) 
We need sample data and desire output to find an answer faster, otherwise we will be wasting time guessing what you need. You also could create your schema with data using **http://www.sqlfiddle.com**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`coopmemID` in your WHERE clause is ambiguous. Both tb_cooploan_master and tb_finalpay have such a field, so you have to mark which one you mean. (even though the ON clause makes them equal....)
You probably also want to SELECT tb_finalpay.fpayID and insert the value into tb_finalpay_detail.fpayID

```
INSERT INTO
    tb_finalpay_detail
    (fpayID, cooploanID)
SELECT
    p.fpayID, m.cooploanID
FROM
    tb_cooploan_master as m
INNER JOIN
    tb_finalpay as p
ON
    m.coopmemID = p.coopmemID
WHERE
    m.coopmemID='coop2554853ec74ca6b7c2'
```

Comment: On a side note: the table tb_finalpay_detail seems to be a bit redundant/superfluous. You're sure you need it?